# Wordpress fresh installation showing "User(s) already exists"

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, multisite

I am running two sites in a server. When I tried to create a new one, I am getting the following screen:

[image]

I am afraid, how it came? When I checked the newly created db, tables are not created. So I am in a dilemma.

How can I find a solution for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe It's because you already provided the Database details inside the wp-config.php before proper installation. Can you please check the same?

Comment: Yeah you are right, thanks for the solution. Issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the config file if you have pointed the database properly for the new installation.

I do recommend backing up the existing database before trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Where is the config file? How to "point the database"? These are questions that could arise from your answer. Please try to be more explicit and add details / code to illustrate your answer. Also, if OP's configuration is good, then your answer is not an answer. It should have been a comment instead.

Comment: I already checked the config file, its updated correctly in config file.

Comment: Please try enabling debug mode and check the logs. It may provide some light on the issue.